# Find a group of names that share columns and then for each other name from group find in which other group it appears

Tags: sql, mysql

Given the following table1 schema:

```
+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID      | int             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| NAME    | bigint unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SECONDS | int             | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| LINK    | int             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and the following data in table1

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+
| ID | NAME    | SECONDS | LINK    |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
|  2 |       2 |       1 |       1 |
|  3 |       3 |       1 |       2 |
|  4 |       4 |       1 |       2 |
|  5 |       2 |       2 |       1 |
|  6 |       3 |       2 |       1 |
|  7 |       4 |       2 |       2 |
|  8 |       1 |       2 |       3 |
|  9 |       3 |       3 |       1 |
| 10 |       4 |       3 |       1 |
| 11 |       1 |       3 |       2 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

return the following result

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| NAME    | SECONDS | LINK    |
+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       2 |       3 |
|       1 |       3 |       2 |
|       2 |       1 |       1 |
|       2 |       2 |       1 |
|       3 |       1 |       2 |
|       3 |       2 |       1 |
|       3 |       3 |       1 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

The query should group all `NAME`s that share the same `SECONDS` and `LINK`, for example

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT NAME) AS NAME_list,
  SECONDS,
  LINK    
FROM
  table1
GROUP BY
  SECONDS,
  LINK    
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) > 1;
```

returns

```
+--------------+---------+---------+
| NAME_list    | SECONDS | LINK    |
+--------------+---------+---------+
| 1,2          |       1 |       1 |
| 3,4          |       1 |       2 |
| 2,3          |       2 |       1 |
| 3,4          |       3 |       1 |
+--------------+---------+---------+
```

and then given an input list of `NAME`s, say `(1)`, for each group above where `1` appears, in our case `1,2`, take the remaining `NAME`s from the group, such as `2`, and find all `NAME`s where `2` appears in some other group.

Essentially the problem is to obtain transitive relationships two levels deep, that is since 1 connects to 2, and 2 connects to 3, we need to return `NAME`s 1, 2, and 3. However we do not want to go another level deeper, that is, we are after

```
1 -> 2 -> 3          (two links)
```

but not

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4     (we don't need to return also link to 4)
```

even though based on the group 2,3 we know that 3 also connects to 4 as there exits a group 3,4.

In other words, given an input list of `NAME`s, for each `NAME`, find all rows that are in transitive relationships two links deep A -> B -> C based on shared columns.

If possible how can this query be expressed in SQL?

Comment: Please could you expain the logic why rows 2 and 3 appear in your desired result set (corresponding to ID 8 and ID 11).  They have values for (SECONDS, LINK) that don't appear in any other row.

Comment: @RobEyre Because if a NAME has a link to any other NAME at least once, then I need all the rows from original table1 with that NAME, so even though say ID 8 is not sharing (SECOND, LINK) with any other NAME I still need ID 8 row because ID 1 is at least sharing with ID 2.

Comment: OK I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I think, my example satisfies your question. Removing unnecessary (repetitive) strings is not difficult. You can select rows, beginning with NAMEs from input list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to build this up using self-joins.

Step 1: Prepare a table of which rows have different `NAME` but the same `SECONDS` and `LINK` (A => B):

```
SELECT
    t1.NAME AS leftNAME, t2.NAME AS rightNAME
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.NAME <> t2.NAME
    AND t1.SECONDS = t2.SECONDS
    AND t1.LINK = t2.LINK
```

Results:

```
+----------+-----------+
| leftNAME | rightNAME |
+----------+-----------+
|        2 |         1 |
|        1 |         2 |
|        4 |         3 |
|        3 |         4 |
|        3 |         2 |
|        2 |         3 |
|        4 |         3 |
|        3 |         4 |
+----------+-----------+
```

Step 2: Then self-join this table to get two steps (A => B => C) and apply the constraint that our inital selection is NAME = 1:

```
WITH transitions AS (
    SELECT
        t1.NAME AS leftNAME, t2.NAME AS rightNAME
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.NAME <> t2.NAME
        AND t1.SECONDS = t2.SECONDS
        AND t1.LINK = t2.LINK
)
SELECT 
    one_to_two.leftNAME AS oneNAME,
    two_to_three.leftNAME AS twoNAME,
    two_to_three.rightNAME AS threeNAME
FROM transitions one_to_two
INNER JOIN transitions two_to_three ON
    one_to_two.rightNAME = two_to_three.leftNAME
    AND one_to_two.leftNAME <> two_to_three.rightNAME
WHERE one_to_two.leftNAME IN (1)
```

Results:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+
| oneNAME | twoNAME | threeNAME |
+---------+---------+-----------+
|       1 |       2 |         3 |
+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Step 3: Then join once more to the original table to get any rows that match any of the NAMEs from any of the steps:

```
WITH transitions AS (
    SELECT
        t1.NAME AS leftNAME, t2.NAME AS rightNAME
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.NAME <> t2.NAME
        AND t1.SECONDS = t2.SECONDS
        AND t1.LINK = t2.LINK
), steps AS (
    SELECT 
        one_to_two.leftNAME AS oneNAME,
        two_to_three.leftNAME AS twoNAME,
        two_to_three.rightNAME AS threeNAME
    FROM transitions one_to_two
    INNER JOIN transitions two_to_three ON
        one_to_two.rightNAME = two_to_three.leftNAME
        AND one_to_two.leftNAME <> two_to_three.rightNAME
    WHERE one_to_two.leftNAME IN (1)
)
SELECT DISTINCT table1.NAME, table1.SECONDS, table1.LINK
FROM table1
INNER JOIN steps
   ON table1.NAME IN (steps.oneNAME, steps.twoNAME, steps.threeNAME)
ORDER BY table1.NAME, table1.SECONDS, table1.LINK
```

Results:

```
+------+---------+------+
| NAME | SECONDS | LINK |
+------+---------+------+
|    1 |       1 |    1 |
|    1 |       2 |    3 |
|    1 |       3 |    2 |
|    2 |       1 |    1 |
|    2 |       2 |    1 |
|    3 |       1 |    2 |
|    3 |       2 |    1 |
|    3 |       3 |    1 |
+------+---------+------+
```

Comment: Note the problem is NAME=4 rows should not appear in the result set, that is, even if there exits relationship 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4, I need rows relevant only to names 1, 2 and 3, but not 4.

Comment: Is 2 -> 3 ->4 should appear in result set? Why, if not.

Comment: OK, I changed the answer to apply the constraint at the beginning of the chain (NAME = 1) and include all rows with matching NAME at every step

Comment: @RobEyre Is it possible to optimise this query in any way in mysql? Perhaps using indexed intermediary tables?

Comment: If you want to optimise things, that's a different question.  First step would be to ensure you have an index on (SECONDS, LINK) and another on NAME in the source table.  Then you could examine the output of EXPLAIN on that query and see what further optimisations could be done.  Materialising temporary tables is unlikely to get you much performance gain - it depends how frequently your data changes and how often you're querying it

Comment: @RobEyre Data changes very infrequently and also it is rarely queried. Currently 50 mil rows take about 1 hr for the query to complete. Indexes indeed exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is a little too small to consider this interesting task.
But let's try. Take a look at the example.

```
with nsl as(
select distinct name,concat(seconds,'-',link) SL
from test
)
,l2 as( -- NAMEs that share the same SECONDS and LINK (SL)
select t1.name name1,t2.name name2, t1.sl sl
from nsl t1
left join nsl t2 on t1.sl=t2.sl and t1.name<t2.name
where t2.name is not null
)
-- select t1.name1 name1,t1.name2 name2, t2.name2 name3,t1.sl sl1,t2.sl sl2 
select distinct t1.name1 name1,t1.name2 name2, t2.name2 name3
from l2 t1
left join l2 t2 on 
    (t1.name2=t2.name1 and t2.sl<>t1.sl)
  or(t1.name2<t2.name2 and t2.sl=t1.sl)
where t2.name2 is not null
  and t1.name1 in(1,2,3 ) -- input list
order by t1.name1
```

Result is

| name1 | name2 | name3 | sl1 | sl2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1-1 | 2-1 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 2-1 | 1-2 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 2-1 | 3-1 |

To explain the idea of the solution, I will give the intermediate results of the queries

Subquery `l2` result - NAMEs that share the same SECONDS and LINK (Very similar to the result of your query)

| name1 | name2 | SL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1-1 |
| 3 | 4 | 1-2 |
| 2 | 3 | 2-1 |
| 3 | 4 | 3-1 |

I'll add some test data

```
create table test(ID int,NAME int,SECONDS int,LINK int);
insert  into test values
 (1 ,1 ,1 ,1 )
,(2 ,2 ,1 ,1 )
,(3 ,3 ,1 ,2 )
,(4 ,4 ,1 ,2 )
,(5 ,2 ,2 ,1 )
,(6 ,3 ,2 ,1 )
,(7 ,4 ,2 ,2 )
,(8 ,1 ,2 ,3 )
,(9 ,3 ,3 ,1 )
,(10,4 ,3 ,1 )
,(11,1 ,3 ,2 )
-- added
,(12,5 ,13 ,12 )
,(13,6 ,13 ,12 )
,(14,7 ,13 ,12 )
,(15,7 ,20 ,30 )
,(16,8 ,20 ,30 )
;
```

There result is

| name1 | name2 | name3 | sl1 | sl2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1-1 | 2-1 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 2-1 | 3-1 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 2-1 | 1-2 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 13-12 | 13-12 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 13-12 | 13-12 |
| 5 | 7 | 8 | 13-12 | 20-30 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 13-12 | 20-30 |